# How can i turn the labels in the ggplot for R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, aes, geom-bar

I would like to turn either the plot or the labels to make them fit into a grouping plot.

This is the command i´m using.

```
ggplot(bank,aes(job))+geom_bar(aes(fill=respuesta))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by grouping plot. Do you want to rotate the axis labels? Have you tried `+ coord_flip()` to switch x and y axes or `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))` to rotate the x axis text labels?

Comment: it worked! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solved in comments by @teunbrand:

Add `+ coord_flip()` to switch x and y axes or `+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))` to rotate the x axis text labels.